# Black screen/purple border booting Ubuntu 14.04 after replacing Nvidia card with integrated Intel GMA 3000

Tags: drivers, 14.04, nvidia, intel-graphics

I'm not an Ubuntu expert, but I've been using it for quite some time. One of the most difficult things for me to fix are graphics/X/video driver problems. I usually just reinstall everything when there's an issue since all the data can be brought over, but this time is somewhat different.

The old nVidia GeForce 6800 card on my Dell OptiPlex 745 gave out, so my only option was to revert back to the integrated graphics, which turns out to be **Intel Graphics Media Accelerator (GMA) 3000**. As a result of the change, I've purged all nVidia drivers and uninstalled them. I've also installed the Intel Graphics Driver Installer and went through. However, it didn't seem like any chances were made. When booting up, I get a black screen with a thin purple border.

The only way to boot into the desktop/login screen is going through the GRUB menu (pressing Shift) and selecting the **recovery mode** and selecting **Resume**, a process that takes too long to boot. The other options on the recovery menu (like dpkg) didn't work. I suspect it is just something preventing the correct drivers from loading because it is normal through recovery mode options.

Also, I've read about the option to edit the commands by adding "nomodeset" in the boot entry on GRUB, but I'd rather not try those until the problem is identified and fixed.

Can anyone guide me into fixing this or direct me to where something like this has been solved before? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you connect to the internet in Grub ?

Comment: Your graphics card should work. Boot a text console (add `text` to the grub command line) then make sure your packages are up-to-date (`sudo apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`) and remove any /etc/X11/xorg.conf you have leftover from the previous setup. Or you could just re-install 14.04.1, which might be easier.

Comment: @user308564 No, I can't connect to the internet in Grub.

Comment: @bain packages are up-to-date. There aren't any xorg.conf leftover, but there is the xorg.conf.failsafe. Adding the text console didn't do much. Do I disable the quiet splash and uncomment the console? It might be easier to re-install. However before, I received a similar issue with the LiveUSB boot.

Comment: Yes just replace "quiet splash" with "text" and Ubuntu will not start Xorg. Can you ssh in when you get the black screen? If so, check the output of `dmesg` and /var/log/Xorg.0.log for any errors.

Comment: @bain I just tried reinstalling 14.04.1 and the issue is still there. I edited grub to use "nomodeset" and the boot is okay, but slow. I turned off some Unity animations using Compiz and it is somewhat faster now. I don't think the Intel GMA was correctly recognized even after installing the Intel Graphics Installer, so I guess this will just have to do for now. dmesg outputs a lot, so I"m not sure if anything was abnomral. Does ssh require Something similar to PuTty or is it installed by default? I have yet to install that.

Comment: @bain The black screen doesn't allow you to do anything, not even open a terminal. Thanks for the help anf quick responses, by the way! What other command outputs should I be looking at?

Comment: Since it crashes on a fresh install it is a bug, which should be reported on Launchpad. The fact that it works with `nomodeset` indicates a problem with kernel mode setting. You could try [installing the most recent mainline kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds) and see if that fixes the issue. If you install openssh-server you can connect to your PC from another system. You might be able to connect and check the kernel log after the hang, but this is only possible if it has hung just the GPU and not everything else.

Comment: I've that a try in the next couple of weeks. Thanks again!